# Test existing a substring in string shell

Tags: shell

I have two parameters:
the list of linux group of user

```
groupsUsers=$(id -nG ${utilisateur})
```

the list of all the group linux of users (linux groups + applications)

```
list_all_groups=$(curl -u GET "${edge_admin_nodes}_${port_http}"/applications/lists)
```

How can I test if the groupsUsers exist in `list_all_groups` or no, and in the case "no" I store the result in a variable ?

I did this solution but I'm not sure that working.

```
for groupUser in ${groupsUsers}
do 
if echo "$list_all_groups" | grep -o "$groupUser" then

        echo "${groupUser}"


    then
        my_result=$( echo "$groups,$groupUser" )
         result="${groups},\"${groupUser}\""
fi
done
```

Comment: What format does `$list_all_groups` have?

Comment: list_all_groups= Appli_1,Appli_2,Appli_3, group_linux_2

and the groupsUsers = group_linux_1, group_linux_2, group_linux_3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I prefer proper parsing. However, a common solution is to put the delimiter around both strings, e.g.:

```
if echo ",$list_all_groups," | grep -q ",$groupUser," then
```

This checks a string that has commas around the original list (so we don't have to deal with beginning/end-of-string differences) against a particular entry, also with its delimiters, so that we don't match a groupUser of `foo` with an entry in list_all_groups of `foobar`.